# How to enter every directory in current path and execute script

Tags: bash, ls, cd-command

I want to enter every directory retuned by `ls` command and execute script.

I tried this (and many other things), but it just does not work

```
ls  | awk '{print $1" && pwd"}' | xargs cd
```

How to do it without for loop?

Comment: Why specifically `ls` and not a for-loop? The for-loop would be the easier approach, and in addition it won't break on directories containing whitespace or quotes, like you'll get problems with when parsing `ls` output.

Comment: See also: [How to go to each directory and execute a command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470165/bash-go-to-each-directory-and-execute-a-command) at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can, use `find` as suggested in other answers, `xargs` is almost always to be avoided.

But if you still want to use `xargs`, a possible alternative is the following:

```
printf '%s\0' */ | xargs -0 -L1 bash -c 'cd -- "$1" && pwd' _
```

Some notes:

1. `*/` expands to the list of directories in the current folder, thanks to the trailing slash
2. `printf` with `\0` (null byte) separates the elements one for each line
3. the option `-L1` to `xargs` makes it to execute once for every input line and the option `-0` makes it separate the input on the null byte: filenames can contain any character, the command doesn't break!
4. `bash` removes the double quotes and pass it to the inline script as a single parameter, but `cd` should put double quotes again to interpret it as a single string; using `--` makes the `cd` command robust against filenames that start with a hyphen
5. to avoid the *strange* use of `$0` as a parameter, is usual to put a first dummy argument `_`

Comment: I knew `echo *` but was not aware of `*/`. And putting an underscore as the 1st argument is a neat trick.

Comment: thx a lot, I'm learning bash and this is very helpful.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: thank for editing and providing a more robust command.

Comment: This is actually better than `find`, as it can use `xargs` in parallel (`-P`) much more easily.

Answer (score 19):

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "$0" && pwd' {} \;
```

Swap `pwd` for your script. And `.` for the root directory name, if it's not the "current" directory.

You have to wrap the exec clause in `bash -c "..."` because of the way `-exec` works. `cd` doesn't exist in its limited environment, but as you can see by running the above command, when you bring in bash to do the job, everything runs as predicted.

**Edit:** I'm not sure why 2011 Oli didn't think of `-execdir` but that's probably a faster solution:

```
find . -type d -execdir pwd \;
```

Comment: The reason `cd` alone do not work is because it is a shell builtin, nothing to do with the environment.

Comment: Nice work Oli.  I added `maxdepth` here as mentioned before, also since it seems to imply current subdirectories i removed `.`: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && pwd" \;`

Answer (score 3):

You [shouldn't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in the first place.

You can use GNU `find` for that and its `-execdir` parameter, e.g.:

```
find . -type d -execdir realpath "{}" ';'
```

or more practical example:

```
find . -name .git -type d -execdir git pull -v ';'
```

and here is version with `xargs`:

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I% sh -c 'cd "%" && pwd && echo Do stuff'
```

For more examples, see: [How to go to each directory and execute a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470165/bash-go-to-each-directory-and-execute-a-command) at SO

Answer (score 2):

Maybe take a look at using `find` with `-exec`?

Answer (score 2):

**The find command**

The find command is pretty handy. It can generate a list of files or directorise in or below a specified directory, and it can also execute a command on each item in that list of results. (Note: if you're using a multi-user system, make sure to read the security considerations section of the Findutils documentation for the find command.)

The options to the find command that we need are -type d which tells find to return the names of every directory within the specified path, and -exec command '{}' \; which tells find to run command on the results. For example:

```
find /media/music/flac -type d -exec ~/tag-flac-with-rg.sh '{}' \;
```

This tells find to return every directory in or below the path /media/music/flac and then run the tag-flac-with-rg.sh script on each directory found. The '{}' is replaced by each directory name found, and gets passed as an argument to the tag-flac-with-rg.sh script. The \; marks the end of the arguments list to the tag-flac-with-rg.sh script.
may be this will help u

Comment: No need to quote `{}`, and a `-maxdepth 1` could be useful, if the OP do not want to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: @enzotib I did not know about the -maxdepth 1, thx

Answer (score 2):

Just for curiosity I tried to take your example and make it work. There is **no reason to use this technique** instead of the `find` command.

> **Note:** Thanks to *enzotib* for pointing it out, this does not work for directory names containing spaces or any other characters that
>   make `awk` think the name consists of several fields.

To make your example work a few tweaks should be made. But at first see the code:

```
ls -l | grep ^d | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'cd $0; ls'
```

The first two commands make sure that only directories are listed. Since `ls` long listing contains a `d` as the first character for directories, the `grep` command selects only these lines.

With `awk` only the last column is displayed in every line. `NF` is a built-in variable in `awk` holding the maximum number of fields. Thus printing `$NF` displays the last field.

Finally `xargs` needed to be tamed to run the specified script with only one parameters at a time. (I know this kind-of defeats its purpose.) Otherwise the script could not be run for every directory *without a for loop*.

And to work around the built-in `cd` barrier, we call `bash` with `-c`. Also note that `$0` becomes the first parameter instead of `$1`.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you have directories names containing spaces, `$NF` gives only the last word of the name. This is one of the reason why people is suggested to not parse `ls` output.

Comment: This is a valid point and I do not see an easy workaround without creating a lengthy `awk` script. I was trying to demonstrate how the original thinking could work (and to convince the OP not to use it, because it is at least not elegant). Thank you for pointing it out, I'll update the answer.

Comment: See my answer working with `xargs`.

Comment: thx a lot, I'm learning bash and this is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Other alternative:

```
for directory in *
do
  (cd $directory && awk '{print $1" && pwd"}')
done
```